# Deceptively Simple: Check If Data Is Returned From MySQL In One Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here is a simple scenario I am contemplating. I have a query that is executed on a MySQL database from PHP. I would like to check if any data was returned from the query. However, in order to perform that check, it pulls out one of the rows of returned data.

Look at this example, and its comments:

```
$booksGrabber = ("SELECT * FROM table");

if (!$booksGrabber) {
  //Query failed, perhaps a syntax error
  exit;
}

if (!mysql_result($booksGrabber, 0)) {
  //No data was returned :(
  exit;
}

while ($book = mysql_fetch_assoc($booksGrabber)) {
  //mysql_result() stole the first row of returned data
  //So if I was expecting the loop to display 4 results,
  //I only get 3...
}
```

How can I check if data was returned from the database without running two queries (one to check, the other to display all of the data) or having one of the rows stolen?

Comment: Also, you should read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You might want to start reconsidering the mysql library you are using.

Comment: Thank you, but the client's server my application will run on doesn't have the MySQLi extension. Otherwise I would have used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows). It was as simple as it looked.

EDIT: If you want more complicated, add [`mysql_data_seek`](http://php.net/mysql-data-seek)`($booksGrabber,0)`.

Comment: For some reason I always assumed that `mysql_num_rows()` removed all of the data from the `mysql_query()` resource when it was executed. Yes this properly checks to see if data was returned and doesn't steal any of the rows from the resource. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple: **mysql_query()** function that runs the query will return false on error and then you can use mysql_num_rows() for the count. So you can do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
if (!$result) {
    print('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} elseif (mysql_num_rows() == 0) {
    print("no results");
} else {
   // You can use safely data from the query :)
}
```

Comment: This is already covered in the question. The question is about finding out if the **successful** query returned any rows.